# Getting 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /*' error even though single servlet is present

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

I am getting an error even though there is a single servlet in my code.

```
WARN  2021-04-06 21:52:42,874  [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED ServletHandler@93501be{FAILED}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /*: git.service.http.MyServlet68360fb9[mapped:EMBEDDED:null],io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-713e49c3[mapped:EMBEDDED:null]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /*: git.service.http.MyServlet68360fb9[mapped:EMBEDDED:null],io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-713e49c3[mapped:EMBEDDED:null]
```

Below is my code:

```
environment
   .getApplicationContext()
   .addServlet(
           new ServletHolder(
                 new MyServlet(
                        injector.getInstance(HttpRepositoryResolver.class))),
           “/*“);
```

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: How do you think Jersey is ran? Jersey is actually a Servlet application.

Comment: Oh okay. So what changes should I make in my code to fix this? @PaulSamsotha

Comment: You need to change the path of the servlet you are trying to register. Jersey has this option of forwarding requests to other servlets, but for this to work Jersey would need to be registered as a Servlet _Filter_ , but I don't think Dropwizard has any configuration option to do this. You would need to disable Dropwizard's Jersey (not sure if possible) and manually register Jersey's ServletContainer as a servlet filter. This is bad solution. I wouldn't recommend it (even if it was possible). Change the path of the servlet. Period.

Comment: Does that even work (just changing the path)? I would assume that even after doing that, Jersey would still consume all requests with its /* path.

Comment: I changed the path and it worked. What I did not know here was JerseyServletContainer uses the same path. Thank you so much for help!! @PaulSamsotha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `git.service.http.MyServlet` and `io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer` are registered to the url-pattern `/*`.

Keep in mind that with Servlets, there's no such thing as optional handling of a request.

If the requested resource matches the url-pattern, it's sent to that Servlet, it MUST handle that request, it cannot go "oh, nah, not for me, let someone else handle this request".

I would suggest putting Jersey on something specific like `/api/*` or `/rest/*` as a url-pattern.

Comment: I changed the path and it worked. What I did not know here was JerseyServletContainer uses the same path. Thank you so much for help!! @Joakim Erdfelt